# Swift - Activity View Controller. When sharing a "zip" file, how to disable the "fail to fetch thumbnail" message?

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

So... I am sharing a zip file using activity view controller. Usually for images and stuff, the system automatically generates a thumbnail... but I am sharing "zip". Is there anyway to turn off the console message saying that it can't generate thumbnail? Thanks.

This is the console error message:

```
[Fetching] LPFileMetadataProviderSpecialization failed to retrieve a thumbnail from QuickLookThumbnailing (Error Domain=QLThumbnailErrorDomain Code=0 "Could not generate a thumbnail")
```